# Lazy<T> evaluation within debugger display. "The function evaluation requires all threads to run."

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a class that has many child collections, which are all lazy loaded using Lazy < T >. When debugging is it possible to have those child collections display even if they are not loaded? Or to force evaluation when debugging? Here is a screenshot of the quick watch on one of the child collections. The message the debugger displays is "The function evaluation requires all threads to run.", which makes sense to me, I just want these child collections to be more debugger friendly.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the easy way but in VisualStudio you can create your own debug visualizers for specific types. So you could create a visualizer that evaluated the Lazy to get the value and then expose the result to be visualized again.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379596(v=vs.80).aspx
or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/AuthoringVisualizers.aspx